# AngularJS Select List doesnt match selected Item

Tags: javascript, html, rest, angularjs

I have a global controller in my AngularJS application which provides me with a array containing Attendee objects. Want i want is to modify my CourseRegistration Model which contains one specific attendee object. In the edit window I d like to get a dropdown with all possible attendees whereas there should be the current attendee selected.

I have the following code in my html:

```
        <select ng-model="courseRegistration.attendee" ng-options="attendeeSelectItem.name for attendeeSelectItem in attendeeSelectItems"></select>
```

If I print out `courseRegistration.attendee` with JSON.stringify and do the same with the corresponding option they print out the same object (same id, same name etc.). But if I do something like (`courseRegistration.attendee == attendeeSelectItem`) for the two identical objects, then I get false.

So my question is how can I make sure that the currently selected item (stored in courseRegistration.attendee) gets matched with the corresponding object in my list (which is used by options) ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ddCy/

Greets
Marc

Comment: kindly share your fiddle or plunker demo

Answer (score 0):

Essentially when you use an array of objects to populate a select, it selects the entire object, not just the one item you're seeing in the select list.

See this question for detail and example code: [Problems when using ng-options and ng-switch together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755204/problems-when-using-ng-options-and-ng-switch-together/17756004)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've got something like the following in your controller?

`$scope.courseRegistration = {attendee: {id: 2, name: "A Person"}}`

If so, the reason the comparison fails is that although the object may have the same properties as the one currently selected, it refers to a different object in memory and therefore isn't classed as equal.

Now as a quick hack you could stringify them and then compare, however the correct approach would be either to set the current value by key:

`$scope.courseRegistration = {attendee: attendeeSelectItems[1]};`

Or just store the id/name and set your `ng-options` condition to bind to just that value:

```
$scope.courseRegistration = {attendee: 1};

<select ng-model="courseRegistration.attendee" ng-options="attendeeSelectItem.id as attendeeSelectItem.name for attendeeSelectItem in attendeeSelectItems"></select>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I like approach 1 with the value by key. That means I would have to loop through all attendeSelectItems to find out which matches the current course registration?

Comment: Difficult to say really as the fiddle you posted doesn't actually show what you're trying to do

Comment: Well what I do is I get the current courseRegistration from a REST ressource... and one item which is contained in this courseRegistration is the attendee object. On the other hand I do a REST call to get all available attendees (array containing all attendees). And what I d like to get is that if I edit this courseRegistration the attendee item contained within it is matched against the corresponding attendee object in the attendees array. How would the option with stringify look like?